# in knockout, what is the difference between using attr{.....} and not?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I had a read of the documentation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html but could not understand why

```
 <img data-bind="attr: {src: imgname}"/>
```

works but

```
 <img data-bind="src: imgname"/>
```

does not...

---

What exactly does this `attr` binding do and what is so special about `src`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should the `"src: imgname"` work?

There are only a couple of built-in bindings in Knockout for controlling text appearance and these are the following:

- visible
- text
- html
- css
- style
- **attr**

So as you see `src` is not in the list. All the built-ones are more or less self explenatory but when you want to bind to some other attribute without a built in support e.g. `src` you need to use the generic `attr` syntax.

As also mentioned in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html):

> The **attr binding provides a generic way to set the value of any
>   attribute** for the associated DOM element. This is useful, for example,
>   when you need to set the title attribute of an element, **the src of an
>   img tag**, or the href of a link based on values in your view model

Answer (score 1):

'attr' in data-bind html5 attribute is predefined binding by Knoclout.JS, on the contrary, 'src' in the second example is not.